# QT - check for device behind COM ports?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I'm checking for available COM ports on the system like this:

```
 QList<QSerialPortInfo> com_ports = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
 QSerialPortInfo port;
 ui->ScanPorts->clear();
        foreach(port, com_ports)
        {
            ui->ScanPorts->addItem(port.portName());
        }
        ui->ScanPorts->addItem("Scan ports...");
```

I want to check if there is a device behind that COM port, so that the user of the application can't connect to an "empty" COM port. You can check for `port.isValid();` but that is not enough.

> solution - by comment Michael Vincent

Because I know what type of device should be behind the COM port I can check the DSR signal: Ox10 is pinoutSignal DSR (Data set ready)

```
 int checkForDataSetReady = serialport->pinoutSignals();
 checkForDataSetReady = 0x10 & checkForDataSetReady;
 if(checkforDataSetReady == 0x10)
 {
     //do stuff
 }

//or like this
if(DATA_SET_READY != (DATA_SET_READY & serialport->pinoutSignals())){}
```

Comment: For checking for an device you will have to open that device, perform a check if data could be sent (and read on the other side) and close the port again. You cannot just call something like port->isDeviceConneced()... Except you subclass and create that on your own...

Comment: @Pim Do you know what type of device you are checking to see connected?  Or could it be any device?

Comment: @MichaelVincent Yes, I know what type of device it is. It is a robotic controller.

Comment: In that case, I would look at whether the serial control lines are used (I assume Qt can read the control lines) or look for a command you can send to the controller that won't do anything, like a "no op" or some such, then open the port, send the "no op", wait for a reply or no then close the port.  I've done this in the past as part of an auto-find process.

Comment: @MichaelVincent yes, thank you. I can read the `pinoutSignals()` from the serial. That way I think I can check the DCD signal (Data Carier Detect) if there is a connection established.